# Solid-state relay input characteristics

Tags: datasheet, solid-state-relay, bias

I am a bit confused by some of the specification on this solid state relay [LD00KM](https://www.teledynedefenseelectronics.com/relays/Datasheets%20MSSR/LD00KM_Datasheet.pdf). I am looking at the case in which this relay is used in the 2 Terminal Input (Direct Drive) Configuration as shown in Figure 1 - B.

Looking at the INPUT (CONTROL) SPECIFICATIONS Section (when used in the 2 terminal configuration) it lists the input supply range is 4.2 - 32 VDC, and it is accompanied by Note 1. Note 1 says that for any input voltages above 6 V a series resistor should be added in series with the bias. They tell you to pick a resistor equal to or less than that shown in Figure 5. My questions are as follows:

1. What is the purpose of adding this resistor? Based on Figure 3, it looks like there is some sort of current limiting operation above ~5-6 V, but why have the resistor if there is already some limiting circuit?
2. With the addition of the resistor, does the Input Voltage Range they specify (4.2 - 32 VDC) apply to the voltage before the series resistor or to the voltage seen at the bias pin (after the resistor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the datasheet has a typo: note 1 refers to figure 4, not figure 5.

Also, in note 1, it actually reads "... Use the **standard resistor value** equal to or less than the value found in Figure [sic] 4". This is important to mention because you can't just pick an arbitrarily low resistor for your convenience or everyone would pick the degenerate case of "zero ohm" resistor.

Now onto your questions. It is true that there is internal current limiting that takes place inside the device as you correctly observed from the plateau of the current graph in fig 3. The reason for this external resistor isn't for current limiting. The real reason is when you increase the voltage across a current-limited element (we call this the compliance voltage), that excess voltage turns into heat - the device isn't designed to handle the excess heat from high (>6V) compliance voltages. Remember, the power dissipated is V x I. If I is fixed at the 25mA, then the power dissipated is proportional to the voltage dropped. So the idea is to use an external resistor to burn off the excess voltage and therefore the excess heat outside the SSR instead of inside the SSR.

Why wouldn't they design it to handle the excessive voltage? Simply because of cost and/or market. Most users will use this with low (<6V) bias voltages for most logic level controls. For those that don't, they're stuck with adding their own resistor to burn off heat. Sure the manufacture could include complete turnkey circuitry to handle the full voltage range (Crydom does this with their line), but it's a compromise.

With the resistor, the 4.2 - 32VDC spec is the input BEFORE the resistor. Think, if that was the spec. after the resistor, you wouldn't need the resistor! However, the control input is still limited to 18V in the 3-terminal setup.

Here's a more detailed block diagram on what's going on inside:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMaqU5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>